# How do i implement my runnable to check recursivly?

Tags: java, multithreading, graphics, runnable

Hello I have made this program which creates a maximum of 15 balls randomly placed on the screen and each one has its own runnable, however, my issue is that runnable only runs once on each button press when I want it to continuously check to see if the ball is out of bounds. How would I do this I move the implementation of the runnable into paintComponent and it works but I don't want to do that.

Here is the code that is executed every button press;

```
public static void addBall() throws InterruptedException {
    Ball.balls[BallListener.balls] = new Ball();
    ballPanel.add(Ball.balls[BallListener.balls]);
    Runnable r = new BallRunnable();
    Thread t1 = new Thread(r);
    t1.start();
   try {
        t1.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(BallComponent.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

need to make it so it runs the runnable repeatedly for multiple balls, I would also like to have each ball have its own runnable. here is the code for the runnable;

```
public class BallRunnable implements Runnable {

private static Random rand = new Random();
public static double speed = 0.2f;
public static boolean end = false;

public BallRunnable() {

}

public void run() {
    boundsCheckY1();
    boundsCheckX1();
    boundsCheckY2();
    boundsCheckX2();
}

public void boundsCheckX1() {
    int temp;

    for (int i = 0; i < BallListener.balls; i++) {
        double x = Ball.balls[i].getXCo();
        if (x < 1) {
            temp = rand.nextInt(5) + 1;

            if (temp == 1) {
                Ball.balls[i].setGoRight(true);
                Ball.balls[i].setGoLeft(false);
                Ball.balls[i].setGoUp(false);
                Ball.balls[i].setGoDown(false);
                Ball.balls[i].setDiagonalUp(false);
                Ball.balls[i].setDiagonalDown(false);
            } else if (temp == 2) {
                Ball.balls[i].setGoRight(true);
                Ball.balls[i].setGoLeft(false);
                Ball.balls[i].setGoUp(true);
                Ball.balls[i].setGoDown(false);
                Ball.balls[i].setDiagonalUp(false);
                Ball.balls[i].setDiagonalDown(false);
            } else if (temp == 3) {
                Ball.balls[i].setGoRight(true);
                Ball.balls[i].setGoLeft(false);
                Ball.balls[i].setGoUp(false);
                Ball.balls[i].setGoDown(true);
                Ball.balls[i].setDiagonalUp(false);
                Ball.balls[i].setDiagonalDown(false);
            } else if (temp == 4) {
                Ball.balls[i].setGoRight(true);
                Ball.balls[i].setGoLeft(false);
                Ball.balls[i].setGoUp(false);
                Ball.balls[i].setGoDown(false);
                Ball.balls[i].setDiagonalUp(true);
                Ball.balls[i].setDiagonalDown(false);

            } else if (temp == 5) {
                Ball.balls[i].setGoRight(true);
                Ball.balls[i].setGoLeft(false);
                Ball.balls[i].setGoUp(false);
                Ball.balls[i].setGoDown(false);
                Ball.balls[i].setDiagonalUp(false);
                Ball.balls[i].setDiagonalDown(true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This repeats for all 4 sides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you don't want the new threads to complete, if so put a loop within the run method with an appropriate sleep interval to keep the thread alive.

Comment: I can't seem to make this happen without making the application freeze and i need it running in the background as its just a checker.